# Ikhtilaf and kufr

Tags: salat, fiqh, kufr

It is narrated in al-Fasl fi’l-Milal wa’l-Ahwa’ wa’l-Nihal, 3/128:

> Ibn Hazm said: We narrated from ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab (me Allah be pleased with him), Mu’aadh ibn Jabal, Ibn Mas’ood  and a number of the Sahaabah (may Allah be pleased with them), and from Ibn al-Mubaarak, Ahmad ibn Hanbal, Ishaaq ibn Raahawayh (may Allah have mercy on them), and from 17 of the Sahaabah in total (may Allah be pleased with them) that the one who deliberately and consciously does not offer an obligatory prayer until the time for it ends is a kaafir and an apostate. This is also the view of ‘Abd-Allah ibn al-Maajishoon, the companion of Maalik. And it was the view of ‘Abd al-Malik ibn Habeeb al-Andalusi and others.

It is narrated in al-Muhalla (2/15):

> He (may Allah have mercy on him) said: And it was narrated from ‘Umar, ‘Abd al-Rahmaan ibn ‘Awf, Mu’aadh ibn Jabal, Abu Hurayrah and others among the Sahaabah (may Allah be pleased with them) that the one who deliberately does not offer one obligatory prayer until the time for it ends is a kaafir and an apostate.

For those who are of the view that it is not kufr to leave the salah, how do you respond to the following narrations by Ibn Hazm? From the 2nd narration especially, it feels extremely clear that the one who misses even 1 prayer, is deemed a kafir. After all, the narration is very specific, however, I have pulled the following sources from this site: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/52923/is-the-person-who-prays-friday-prayer-only-not-a-kaafir, so I don't know how trustworthy this text even is.

Likewise, In matters of ikhtilaf, for example, if one follows the majority opinion that leaving the salah is not kufr, and is convinced by this, and he leaves the salah and is convinced that he's Muslim due to his following of that valid opinion, in the eyes of Allah, is he still deemed a kafir, or is he excused in this matter because had he known it was kufr, he would not leave the salah?

Comment: Not exactly. For starters, none of the replies in that question mention these narrations I pulled up. I feel like for those who feel like leaving the salah is not kufr, these narrations are important to address as they r to me, very clear, at least from the islamqa article. Secondly, my 2nd question isn't address at all in any of those replies. I feel like it's just as important if not more as well.

Comment: These statements of ibn Hazm are claims he didn't mention any sanad/evidence for neither in al-Muhalla nor in his al-Milal wa an-Nihal they contradict other statements in al-Muhalla. However, there are statements of sahabah speaking generally about not praying being kufr without mentioning of an amount. Further, his book al-Fasil fi l-Milal wa an-Nihal isn't a fiqh reference. Finally ibn Hazm is a dhahiri scholar (so if a report says "as-salah" he interprets it as one prayer/entity even if the term is referring to the genus). At his time several hadith sources have not yet reached al-Andalus.

Comment: Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen who said: What appears to be the case from the evidence is that he does not become a kaafir unless he gives up prayer all the time, in the sense that he has decided not to pray, so he does not pray Zuhr, ‘Asr, Maghrib, ‘Isha’ or Fajr. This is the one who is a kaafir. But if he prays one or two obligatory prayers, then he is not a kaafir and he cannot truly be described as having given up prayer. The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Between a man and shirk and kufr stands his giving up prayer (al-salaah)” and he did not say “salaah (a prayer)”.

Comment: I appreciate the response to this. If possible, could you address my 2nd question with evidences/ sources to back up whichever answer you make of?